# Clojure - Read large file line by line that is using different character for newline

Tags: clojure

I need to read in large csv file line by line. My only problem is that this file is not using \n for newline, but char 2. So what I would need is something line `line-seq` but with the ability to specify newline char.

Comment: [Under the hood](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2954) what clojure uses is [java.io.BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) which doesn't provide that functionality directly, you'd have to build your own based on `read` or search for some 3rd party library

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669404/processing-a-file-character-by-character-in-clojure for an implementation of `char-seq`, which modifying to your requirement should be straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

I am interested in the use case ;)

So I put up a quick library that hopefully does the job.

https://github.com/hellonico/custom-reader

Basically explained by the 2 test cases, so copy pasting them here:

With file test.txt

```
thisisaline 2thisisanotherline2thisisathirdline
```

This gives:

```
(deftest test-with-special-line-ending-char-has-3-lines
 (let [
   rdr (custom.java.BufferedReader. (java.io.FileReader. "resources/test.txt") \2)
  ]
  (is (= 3 (count (line-seq2 rdr))))))
```

And with a regular file:

```
this is
counted
as
only one line
```

This gives

```
   (deftest test-with-normal-line-endings    (let [
      rdr (custom.java.BufferedReader. 
            (java.io.FileReader. "resources/test2.txt") \2)
     ]
     (is (= 1 (count (line-seq2 rdr))))))
```

Let's see if this passes your large csv test.