# How can I fill the 2d array in clojure with loop like matrix that we do in JAVA if I have a list of the characters

Tags: arrays, clojure

I want to fill 2d array in clojure like we do in java

I have provided the example of java. I want to do like this in Clojure

```java
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
int row=sc.nextInt();
int col=sc.nextInt();
realMatrix=new String[row][col];
String[] in=new String[row];
for(int k=0;k<row;k++) {
    in[k]=sc1.nextLine();
}
for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {
    char[] charArry=in[i].toCharArray();
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++) {
        realMatrix[i][j]=Character.toString(charArry[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processing a file character by character in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669404/processing-a-file-character-by-character-in-clojure)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and what problems you have faced.  And since Clojure runs on the JVM you can just as fine reuse your existing Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input (`lines`) is valid (it contains the correct number of rows and each row contains the correct number of characters), it can be parsed with

```clj
(vec (map #(clojure.string/split % #"") (drop 2 lines)))
```

If your input looks like `lines` below, you'll want to filter out the `!`s:

```clj
(def lines
  ["3"
   "5"
   "abcde!!!"
   "FGHIJ!!!"
   "klmno!!!"
   "!!!!!!!!"
   "!!!!!!!!"])

(defn split-row [row n-cols]
  (vec (take n-cols (clojure.string/split row #""))))

(defn parse-matrix [lines]
  (let [n-rows (Integer. (first lines))
        n-cols (Integer. (second lines))
        matrix-lines (take n-rows (drop 2 lines))]
    (vec (map #(split-row % n-cols) matrix-lines))))
```

If you really want to parse it as it is read from standard input:

```clj
(defn parse-matrix-stdin []
  (let [n-rows (Integer. (read-line))
        n-cols (Integer. (read-line))
        matrix-lines (take n-rows (repeatedly read-line))]
    (vec (map #(split-row % n-cols) matrix-lines))))
```