# How to update the value of the 2D vector at particular index in clojure?

Tags: arrays, clojure

I'm solving a finding treasure problem and I want to change my vector data value. So, How can I do that?

I tried so many things but nothing worked for me. I tried assoc, update, assoc-in, update-in and all.

```clj
(println (update-in data [row col] "+"))

(def data1 (-> data (assoc-in [0 0] \+)))

(println data1)
```

So, my vector is like this

```clj
["---#--###----" 
 "---#---#-#---" 
 "-#-####---##-" 
 "-#------#----" 
 "-############" 
 "------------@"]
```

and I want change `-` with `+`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processing a file character by character in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669404/processing-a-file-character-by-character-in-clojure)

Comment: You three should team up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56333082/input-file-into-2d-vector-in-clojure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334248/read-file-and-create-vector-in-clojure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334579/how-to-update-the-value-of-the-2d-vector-at-particular-index-in-clojure

Comment: It’s amazing how many of these there are... I might write a blog on the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to refine your data structure so that `assoc-in` works with it.  Functions like `assoc-in` and `update-in` operate on nested key-value data structures, such as maps and vectors.  I'd recommend an ingest function like the following:

```
(defn create-maze [m]
  (into [] (map vec) m))
```

This provides you with a vector of vectors, similar in nature to a two-dimensional array.  You can then provide a helper function to print the maze to screen:

```
(defn print-maze [m]
  (doseq [line m]
    (->> line (apply str) println)))
```

Now that you have a way of getting back and forth from a string representation, you can now use `assoc-in` on the intermediate form to create mazes with altered contents:

```
(->
  (create-maze data)
  (assoc-in [0 0] \+)
  (assoc-in [3 4] \+)
  print-maze)
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings and vectors are immutable in Clojure, so you can only create a copy of the object with updated contents.

Also, you can call `assoc` or `update` only on Clojure's built-in data structures. You need to convert the String into a vector first. After updating, you can convert it back to a string by calling `(apply str ...)` on it.

```
(defn to-plus [data x y]
  (update data y (fn [row] (apply str (assoc (vec row) x \+)))))
```